# How to calculate time it takes to send request data to server in android

Tags: google-app-engine, android-networking

How would I write a code in android to calculate time it took to sent data to server.I am using google app engine .I need help in this regard.I googled a lot but not getting the context.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

well it shouldn't be that hard getting those times by using System.currentTimeMillis() before and after to check time elapsed.

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 /* do network operation */ 
 long total = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
```